# Handlebars @partial-block usage

Tags: handlebars.js, partials

I have been trying to pass a template to a partial as explained here: https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/partials.html#partial-blocks.
For instance I have a file `hello.hbs` that contains:

```
Hello
{{> @partial-block }}
```

that I am trying to include inside another file `world.html` as is:

```
{{#> hello }}
World!
{{/hello}}
```

so that it should render:

```
Hello
World!
```

But if I am doing this, I am getting the error `The partial @partial-block could not be found`. However, if I change `hello.hbs` to:

```
Hello
{{ @partial-block }}  <!-- Removed the '>' -->
```

it works. Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually I solved this issue with the comment provided here: https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/1168#issuecomment-247010136.
The error was probably happening because the partial block was not always defined for instance if I was doing:

```
{{#> hello }}
{{/hello}}
```